# Is it possible to customise report export file names?

Tags: civireport

Is it possible to automatically name Report downloads (PDFs or .csv files) to reflect the report title?

(This strikes me as being an obvious thing to do, so apologies if I've missed some equally obvious solution)

Answer (score 4):

The code currently puts all pdf's under CiviReport.pdf (and similar for csv)

Would be good to use the report title as the file name. The code to make the change is here:

CRM/Report/Form.php

search for CiviReport.pdf

If you can make the change, please file an issue and submit a PR against master so it can be included in the next release.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure my php is up to that, but I'll take a look.

Comment: (Also, just after a quick look at that file, it suggests that the csv files would appear as CiviReport.csv, but the files I'm downloading always take the form Report_date-time.csv - is there another file that defines this?)

Comment: Check the call to: CRM_Report_Utils_Report::export2csv which also happens in that file

Comment: Ah - found it :)